# Is preflight requests counted in usage limits?

Tags: google-slides-api

I have a question regarding Slides API usage limits.

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/slides/limits) says that default limits for expensive read requests are 100 per user per 100 second. However, I'm getting `429 Too Many Requests` response way before that amount of requests. And it looks like preflight requests are included in that amount.

Since all those requests are cross-origin, it means that in reality you can send only half of that amount before you start receiving `429 Too Many Requests` responses.

Is it intended behaviour? I understand the reasons behind limiting heavy tasks, but I don't think that responding to preflight request could be considered as heavy (or expensive).

Comment: Please define `preflight request` - which particular methods are you using? Keep in mind that there are also limits for write requests and daily limits. If you go to https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas you can see your usage.

Comment: @ziganotschka — https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request

Comment: On a side-note: As Preflight requests are only present in Browsers you could use the API through any other technology as designed.

Comment: Could you provide your code to see if I can reproduce your issue?

Comment: @ziganotschka I'm talking about this method https://developers.google.com/slides/reference/rest/v1/presentations.pages/getThumbnail, just regular fetch and I don't think I'm using anything else that might be considered as `expensive read request`. 
To reproduce create a presentation with for example 59 slides. then execute this [code](https://pastebin.com/4r1EAizh) from the browser with replaced token and presentationId. 
I think there is no way to get thumbnails for all slides in one requests, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @Smutje yeah, I'm aware of that. Just don't want to bother with the server only for that.

Comment: @user12747262: If do not mind, I would appreciate if you could provide your full code including authentication, token acquisition etc.

Comment: @ziganotschka are you want me to share my google token? Sorry, but I'm definitely not gonna do that. You can take it from the docs, there is a "Try this" section on the right: login execute, and you can see your token in the network panel.

Comment: Of course not. I did not expect you to share your token, but to provide the code containing the token acquisition - sanitized, without any personal data. I did not realize that you obtain the token manually from the "Try this API".

Comment: @ziganotschka I'm not obtaining it manually, but from google extension api, so my current code don't really suit for sharing, since you had to build an extension for it to work.